# Product of digits in an integer python

Tags: python

Product of digits
For a given number x calculate the smallest positive integer for which the product of the digits is equal to the original number.

For example, if x=12 the number 26 has digits 2 and 6 and their product is equal to 12. Also, 26 is the smallest number with this property.

Write a function called product_x with one parameter: x. Return the smallest number with this property.

So they said i should make the integer a string:

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Then how would you write the logic (without any code syntax checking)?

Comment: They gave us a hint:

Comment: They gave us a hint:To do this you need two functions:
digits returns the list of digits. You can do this by converting the number to string then iterating over the letters and convert them back to integers and put them in a list
The function product_x should go through every integer from 1 and check whether the product of digits is correct. Return the number if it is correct. Also this will be the smallest number with this property

Comment: there you go!  then divide your tasks into smaller ones.... 1) convert the number to string 2) ???

Comment: i did this:def digits(n):
l=[]
  if n>0:
  l.append(str(n))
   print l

def product_x(x):
    for i in range(len(l)):
       if (l[i])×(l[i+1])==x:
        print , x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def product_x(num):
    x=10
    while True:
        print (x)
        y=[int(a) for a in str(x)]
        product = 1
        for z in y:
            product*=z
        if product == num:
            return x
        else:
            x+=1
print(product_x(10))
#print(product_x(number))
```

Comment: It fails when you put 8. The answer is 18 but it shows 8.

Comment: it gives the output as 18, considering I'm not selecting any numbers below 10, Could you check again.